# Sparse Matrix error in MLPRegressor

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

### Context

I'm running into an error when trying to use sparse matrices as an input to `sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor`. Nominally, this method is able to handle sparse matrices. I think this might be a bug in `scikit-learn`, but wanted to check on here before I submit an issue.

### The Problem

When passing a `scipy.sparse` input to `sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor` I get:

```
ValueError: input must be a square array
```

The error is raised by the `matrix_power` function within `numpy.matrixlab.defmatrix`. It seems to occur because `matrix_power` passes the sparse matrix to `numpy.asanyarray` ([L137](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py#L137)), which returns an array of size=1, ndim=0 containing the sparse matrix object. `matrix_power` then performs some dimension checks ([L138-141](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py#L138)) to make sure the input is a square matrix, which fail because the array returned by `numpy.asanyarray` is not square, even though the underlying sparse matrix *is* square.

As far as I can tell, the problem stems from `numpy.asanyarray` preventing the dimensions of the sparse matrix being determined. The sparse matrix itself has a size attribute which would allow it to pass the dimension checks, but only if it's not run through `asanyarray`.

I *think* this might be a bug, but don't want to dive around filing issues until I've confirmed that I'm not just being an idiot! Please see below, to check.

If it *is* a bug, where would be the most appropriate place to raise an issue? NumPy? SciPy? or Scikit-Learn?

### Minimal Example

#### Environment

```
Arch Linux
kernel     4.15.7-1

Python     3.6.4
numpy      1.14.1
scipy      1.0.0
sklearn    0.19.1
```

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, Imputer
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor

## Generate some synthetic data

def fW(A, B, C):
    return A * np.random.normal(.3, .1) + B * np.random.normal(.6, .1)

def fX(A, B, C):
    return B * np.random.normal(-1, .1) + A * np.random.normal(-.9, .1) / C

# independent variables
N = int(1e4)
A = np.random.uniform(2, 12, N)
B = np.random.uniform(2, 12, N)
C = np.random.uniform(2, 12, N)

# synthetic data
mW = fW(A, B, C)
mX = fX(A, B, C)

# combine datasets
real = np.vstack([A, B, C]).T
meas = np.vstack([mW, mX]).T

# add noise to meas
meas *= np.random.normal(1, 0.0001, meas.shape)

## Make data sparse
prob_null = 0.2
real[np.random.choice([True, False], real.shape, p=[prob_null, 1-prob_null])] = np.nan
meas[np.random.choice([True, False], meas.shape, p=[prob_null, 1-prob_null])] = np.nan

# NB: problem persists whichever sparse matrix method is used.
real = sparse.csr_matrix(real)
meas = sparse.csr_matrix(meas)

# replace missing values with mean
rmnan = Imputer()
real = rmnan.fit_transform(real)
meas = rmnan.fit_transform(meas)

# split into test/training sets
real_train, real_test, meas_train, meas_test = model_selection.train_test_split(real, meas, test_size=0.3)

# create scalers and apply to data
real_scaler = StandardScaler(with_mean=False)
meas_scaler = StandardScaler(with_mean=False)

real_scaler.fit(real_train)
meas_scaler.fit(meas_train)

treal_train = real_scaler.transform(real_train)
tmeas_train = meas_scaler.transform(meas_train)

treal_test = real_scaler.transform(real_test)
tmeas_test = meas_scaler.transform(meas_test)

nn = MLPRegressor((100,100,10), solver='lbfgs', early_stopping=True, activation='tanh')
nn.fit(tmeas_train, treal_train)

## ERROR RAISED HERE

## The problem:

# the sparse matrix has a shape attribute that would pass the square matrix validation
tmeas_train.shape

# but not after it's been through asanyarray
np.asanyarray(tmeas_train).shape
```

Comment: If it is applying `asarray` to that input, it is not setup to use a sparse matrix.  That wrapping doesn't just hide the shape.  It hides the matrix from further use as matrix.  You need to do your own `toarray`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MLPRegressor.fit() as [given in documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.fit) supports sparse matrix for `X` but not for `y`

> Parameters:
>
> X : array-like or sparse matrix, shape (n_samples, n_features)
>
> ```
> The input data.
> ```
>
> y : array-like, shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_outputs)
>
> ```
> The target values (class labels in classification, real numbers in regression).
> ```

I am able to successfully run your code with:

```
nn.fit(tmeas_train, treal_train.toarray())
```

Comment: Thanks! I suspected I was being an idiot. Confirmed!!